# Is it possible to compile and include C libraries with the Swift package manager?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I've tried to just include the header and c files but they seem to be ignored

Answer (score 5):

it is possible but the usual way to do it is to define a seperate package called 'Csomething' where you simply prefix the C library name with a capital C and host it on Github. The C package only need consist of an empty `Package.swift` file and a `module.modulemap`. In the `module.modulemap` you refer to where the C headers are:

```
module CPackage [system] {
  header "/usr/local/include/myheader.h"
  link "libraryname"
  export *
}
```

Thus in your original package, you simply put a dependency in for the CPackage e.g.:

```
.Package(url: "https://github.com/aleph7/CHDF5.git", majorVersion: 1)
```

and then you can `import CPackage`

https://github.com/aleph7/CHDF5 is a good example of a simple C Package

Comment: this works if it is a system library already in the `/usr/local location` but what about custom C files? Should I compile it into a library and add them to `/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: I'll answer my own question, yes for custom code you will need to create a dynamic library and place them in the same location as the system library. You can then link to them in the `module.modulemap`

Comment: The library can be static as well. Using `swift build` you can build an `.a` library and then drag & drop it into Xcode - given that Xcode is using the same toolchain as `swift build`

Answer (score 1):

Further to @timbo’s answer, here's the full documentation for this feature:

https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/SystemModules.md

The system module support has a number of issues currently, but we have plans for fixes.